# pagination like facebook in codegnaitor

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter-2

i have pages that get all post from database, and i will use pagination class from codeigniter.

but i need to use facebook technical for more post, how can i do that.

my controller :-

```
  public function index($page=1) {

        $options = new Option();
        $options->get();
        $oppArray = array();
        foreach($options as $opt){
            $oppArray[$opt->name]= $opt->value;
        }
        $this->data['options'] = $oppArray;

        //if($this->session->userdata('id'))
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || !empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
        {
            $this->template->set_layout('default');
            $this->template->build('home_view',$this->data);
        }
        else{
            $this->template->set_layout('reg');
            $data['title']= 'الرئيسية || تسجيل الدخول او تسجيل جديد بالموقع';
            $this->template->build('registration_view',$this->data);
        }

/************************************** Post *******************************************************************/

        $this->load->model('blog');

        if(isset($_POST['post']) && (!empty($_POST['post']) || strlen($_FILES['inputUpProfile']['name']) > 0) ){
        if(strlen($_FILES['inputUpProfile']['name']) > 0) 
        {
        $pic = $this->do_upload('inputUpProfile');

        if ($this->input->post('post') == ''){$type="image";} else {$type="image-with-text";}
        }

        else {$pic = ""; $type = "text"; }

            $result = $this->blog->addPost($_SESSION['user_id'], $type  , $this->input->post('post'),$pic);
        }
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){

        $config['base_url'] = site_url("./home/index");
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->blog->countPosts($_SESSION['user_id']);
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['num_links'] = 1;
        $config['use_page_numbers']= True;
        $config['display_pages'] = True; 
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $this->data['blog'] =  $this->blog->getPosts($_SESSION['user_id'], $config['per_page'] , ($page-1)*$config['per_page']); 
        $this->template->build("home_view" , $this->data);      
        }
        else
        {
        $this->template->build('registration_view',$this->data);
        }

    }
```

and the view are:-

```
<div id="inner-page-home">

<div class="boxx" id="doctor">
<div id="doc-title">
    <h1>مـــاذا تعمل الان</h1>
    <a href="#">عرض الكل</a>
</div>

<div id="massge" style="float:right">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('home')?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="upimgstatus">

</div>
<div class="textstatus">
<input id="inputUpProfile" name="inputUpProfile" class="inputUpProfile hidefile" type="file" />
<input type="button" id="PicUpProfile" class="sentpic" value="اضافة صورة">

<input name="post" type="text" id="text" placeholder="اكتب رسالتك هنا ...">
<input type="submit" id="sent" value="إرسال"> 
</div>
</form>
</div>

<div style="clear: both"></div>

<ol class="timeline clear">
  <li class="spine">

  </li>

  <?php 
  $counter=0;
  foreach ($blog as $row) { 
  if($counter % 2 == 0){$class= "right";} else $class="left";
  ?>
  <!-- li class="<? //$class ?>" -->
  <li class="right" id="post_row<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>">
    <i class="pointer"></i>
    <div class="unit">
      <!-- Story -->
      <div class="storyUnit">
        <div class="imageUnit">
        <? if (empty($row->pic)) { ?>
          <a href="#"><img width="32" height="32" alt="" src="images/nopic.png"></a>
          <? } else  { ?>
          <a href="#"><img width="32" height="32" alt="" src="uploads/<?php echo $row->pic; ?>"></a>
          <? } ?>
          <? if ($row->ev_user_id == $_SESSION['user_id']){ ?>
          <div id="delpost" style="float:left"><a href="#" id="deletepost" onClick="delete_post('<?=$row->ev_id;?>'); return false;">X</a></div>
          <? } ?>
          <div class="imageUnit-content">
            <h4><a href="./myaccount/profile/<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->fullname; ?></a></h4>
            <p><?php echo $row->ev_date ?></p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <p><?php echo $row->ev_text; ?></p>
        <? if (!empty($row->ev_pic)) { ?>
        <p><img src="uploads/<?php echo $row->ev_pic ?>" width="250" height="250"</p>
        <? } ?>
      </div>
      <!-- / Story -->

     <!-- Units -->
      <ol class="storyActions" id="storyActions<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>">
<?
$selectComment = mysql_query("select * from comment,users where 
comment.co_postid = '".$row->ev_id."'
and comment.co_userid = users.id order by co_date ");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($selectComment)){
?>
            <div id="resultcomment<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>"></div>
      <div id="resultcomment" style="border-top:1px solid #fff;">
      <a href="./myaccount/profile/<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
      <img src="uploads/<?=$rows["pic"];?>" width="32" height="32" class="rightc" />
      </a>
      <b><a href="./myaccount/profile/<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><?=$rows["fullname"]; ?></a></b>
      <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
      <span><?=$rows["co_comment"]; ?></span>
      <br />
      <span class="commentdate"><?=$rows["co_date"]; ?></span></br></div>

<? } ?>      

      <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
       <input type="text" class="commentwall" id="comment<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>" name="comment<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>" size="41" />
       <input type="hidden" id="postid<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>" name="postid<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>" size="41" value="<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>" />
       <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="add_comment_wall(<?php echo $row->ev_id; ?>)">ارسل</button>
       </form>

      </ol>
      <!-- / Units -->

    </div>
  </li>
   <?php $counter++; } ?>
   <div class="clear"></div>
           <div class="paginate">
            <ul>
                <?=$this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
</ol>



</div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">


            function add_comment_wall($id) {

                //get input data as a array
                var post_data = {
                    'comment': $("#comment"+$id+"").val(),
                    'postid': $("#postid"+$id+"").val()
                     };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/insertCommentWall",
                    data: post_data,
                    success: function(comment) {
                        // return success message to the id='result' position
                        $("#storyActions"+$id+"").append(comment);
                         $("#comment"+$id+"").val("");
                    }
                });



        }
    </script>
```

so, when open this view its display 10 record, and i wont when scroll down browser i need to open from 10 to 20 records

Comment: Have a look at http://vasplus.info/tutorial.php?id=67&topic=Facebook%20and%20Twitter%20style%20load%20more%20contents%20using%20Ajax,%20jquery%20and%20PHP, and modify as required.

Comment: @blo i will try but i cannot joined it can you edit my code

Comment: sorry nobody is here to write code for anyone..you can try something, if you are stuck at something divide your problem in small parts, find solution to them, and if you don't get solution to them you can ask it here.